# Почему стратегия отложенной загрузки генерирует LazyInitializationException в Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazyloading, transaction

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать стратегию отложенной загрузки в Hibernate.
Допустим, есть класс `Student`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")

public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;            
    }
}
```

и класс `Room`, имеющий ссылку на класс `Student` с отношением `one-to-one` и использующий стратегию отложенной загрузки `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms")
public class Room {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    public int number;

    @OneToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false
    )
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Student student;

    public Room(){}

    public Room(int number, Student student) {
        this.id = student.id;
        this.number = number;
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

Для получения сущности `Room` использую функцию `get` сервисного класса `RoomService`:

```
public class RoomService {

    public RoomService(){}

    public Room get(long id) throws DBException {
        Transaction transaction = DBService.getTransaction();
        try {
            Room room = DaoFactory.getRoomDao().get(id);
            transaction.commit();
            return room;
        } catch (HibernateException | NoResultException | NullPointerException e) {
            DBService.transactionRollback(transaction);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }
    }
```

Для получения транзакции используется следующая функция из класса `DBService`:

```
public static Transaction getTransaction(){
        Session session = DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        if (!transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        }
        return transaction;
    }
}
```

Собственно, наконец-то сам вызывающий код:

```
StudentService studentService = new StudentService();
RoomService roomService = new RoomService();
        try {
            Student student = studentService.create(new Student("Вася"));                
            Room room = roomService.create(new Room(5, student));                
            Room room2 = roomService.get(room.id);                   
        }
```

Собственно, проблема в `room2`, так как поле `student` хоть и не `null`, но все поля `room2.student.id` и `room2.student.name` равны `null`. 
При отладке видно, что при вызове функции `get` возникает `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` при попытке получения `room2.student`, то есть данные из базы данных сразу не подгружаются. 
Ввиду того, что транзакция завершена, то эти данные получить уже нельзя.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы данные можно было подгружать позже? Понятно, что можно заменить `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` на `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, но тогда данные будут всегда подгружаться, что не всегда приемлемо. Как правильно должно быть спроектировано приложение, чтобы можно было использовать стратегию отложенной загрузки?

**UPD**
Сам класс `RoomDao` очень короткий:

```
public class RoomDao extends AbstractDao<Room> {

    RoomDao() {
        super(Room.class);
    }
}
```

А это функция `get` класса `AbstractDao`:

```
@Override
public T get(long id) {
return DBService.getSessionFactory()
    .getCurrentSession()
    .get(parameterizedClass, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
    }
```

Comment: К сожалению, не понятна логика Ваших действий и самое главное, что делает DaoFactory.getRoomDao().get(id);. В HIBERNATE персистным может быть только один объект с конкретным Id.

Comment: Для инициализации LAZY надо либо затребовать данные объекта либо выполнить Hibernate.initialize(student) в нужный момент; Это можно сделать и после коммита транзакции. Лишь бы объекты были персистными. Посмотреть является ли объект персистным (то-есть хранится ли он в КЭШе персистности) можно с помощью утилиты http://konopkomikl.ru/2017/06/20/hibernate-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%8d%d1%88%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-first-level-persistence-context-cache/

Comment: @Orthodox для проверки персистентности объекта использую `persistenceUtil.isLoaded(room.student())`. Это выражение возвращает `false`, т.е. получается контекст хранения поля `student` сущности `room` закрыт. Более того, даже если добавить в функцию `get` класса `RoomService` строчку `Hibernate.initialize(room.student());` после строки `Room room = DaoFactory.getRoomDao().get(id);`, то инциализации прокси-объекта `room.student` не произойдёт. Все поля этого объекта равны `null`.

Comment: @Orthodox если же убрать в классе  `Room ` строчку `optional = false`, то всё волшебным образом работает. А всё потому, что отношение (отображение) связи `one-to-one` с общим первичным ключом с параметром `optional = true` не поддерживает отложенную загрузку данных, т.е. работает так же, как и при `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. Почему не рабjтает с `optional = false` - непонятно.

Comment: @Orthodox есть небольшое (но существенное) пояснение к предыдущим моим комментариям. После добавления `Hibernate.initialize(room.student());` все поля `room.student` равны `null`, но если в `main` обратиться к полю `room.student.address`, то адрес считывается нормально. При отсутствии `Hibernate.initialize(room.student());` появлялось исключение `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: persistenceUtil.isLoaded(room.student()) - проверяет не персистность объекта, а то представлен ли он как прокси или как реальный объект (у Вас прокси) и это правильно. После initialize объект у Вас становится загружен (запустите isLoaded и Вы увидите это ). После этого, Вы делаете что-то подозрительное в DaoFactory.getRoomDao().get(id) и пытаетесь инициализировать новый неперсистный объект. Проверить, что объект персистный можно так session.contains(entity);

Comment: @Orthodox если вызвать `session.contains(room.getStudent())` в пределах транзакции, т.е. внутри функции `Room.get` перед строчкой `transaction.commit();`, то результат будет `true`. Если же это выражение поставить после `transaction.commit();`, то выпадет исключение `org.hibernate.HibernateException: contains is not valid without active transaction`. Саму сессию получаю так `DBService.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()`, т.к. ссылка на `SessionFactory` хранится в `DBService`.

Comment: @Orthodox а почему вы считатете, что в `DaoFactory.getRoomDao().get(id)` происходит что-то подозрительное? Я правильно понимаю, речь идёт о функции `AbstractDao.get`? внутри используется обычная функция `session.get`. Или вы что-то другое имели ввиду?

Comment: Наверное, все из-за того, что запрашиваете данные с блокировкой (.get(parameterizedClass, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);). Когда Вы пытаетесь превратить прокси в реальный объект, то идет запрос в БД на получение записи из student с блокировкой, а для блокировки нужна транзакция. В таком случае перед инициализацией прокси открывайте транзакцию или если не предполагается редактирование student не блокируйте его .

Comment: @Orthodox заменил `.get(parameterizedClass, id, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ);` на `.get(parameterizedClass, id);`. Все равно выбрасывает исключение `org.hibernate.HibernateException: contains is not valid without active transaction`. Может дело в том, какая стратегия используется для открытия/закрытия сессии? В моём случае  - это `ManagedSessionContext` - каждому потоку по отдельной сессии. В конфигурации (экземпляр класса Configuration) я прописываю следующее: `configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93630/discussion-between-orthodox-and-golubtsoff).